# Machine learning non linear hypothesis

Tags: machine-learning, rgb, rgbcolor

Can anyone tell me how 50 × 50 pixel images is 7500 if it's in RGB. This is something non linear hypothesis example from Andrew Ng machine learning

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 2):

50x50 pixels, 3 values for each pixel

So 50*50*3 = 7500

3 being the three colors in RGB (red green blue)